# error export 'useSyncExternalStore' (imported as 'p') was not found in 'react' when importing an external library into a new repo

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-date-picker

I am getting the error `export 'useSyncExternalStore' (imported as 'p') was not found in 'react'` when I am importing `@mui/x-date-pickers` from an external npm package into a consuming application also built in react. They are both on the same version of react which is  `"react": "^17.0.1",`

I am expecting that the datepicker works in my consuming application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not code to add here other than the package.json files.

Answer (score 0):

useSyncExternalStore only available on React 18 and above, i think you should update to React 18

Comment: I am unable to update to react 18 :/

Comment: if you cant update to 18, install the previous version of version of the library that runs on react 17